# how to access this bitrate value in this union ?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module that needs to read the value of bitrate from this union :

```
union   iwreq_data
{
    .......
    struct iw_param bitrate;    /* default bit rate */

     ....
}
```

this code is taken form wireless.h anyone knows how I can access get its' value?I mean what struct should I use net_device?wireless_dev?  I'm using linux kernel 2.6.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `union iwreq_data *data`, you can simply use `data->bitrate.value`.

But this structure doesn't permanently exist, so you can't get a pointer to it for a given device. The structure is used when setting or getting parameters for a device, and exists only for the duration of the set/get operation.
When setting the bitrate, the driver saves the new value in a driver-dependent manner, and the structure is released (it's normally allocated on the stack of the setting function).

You can try calling `ieee80211softmac_wx_get_rate` to get it. Give it a pointer to an  uninitialized `union iwreq_data`, and it will fill in the bit rate.

Comment: the problem is how to get to it. I mean using what function/data structure (like wireless_dev or something? )

Comment: Thank you Ugoren, but this `ieee80211softmac_wx_get_rate` function does not exist in kernel 2.6.32

Comment: I saw it in 2.6.18. Maybe 2.6.32 has some replacement. You can search for its callers in 2.6.18, and see what they do in 2.6.32.